# Выборка уникального значение из двух полей

Tags: mysql, sql

в таблице есть 2 поля : token, card. Мне нужно выбрать значение token у которых card не повторяется. То есть на данном примере есть 2 token и 2 card , значения card повторяется, мне нужно выбрать те token у которых card уникальный, не повторяется. Пробовал с помощью DISTINCT но ничего не получилось . Заранее спасибо!

[image: таблица]

Comment: *То есть на данном примере есть 2 token и 2 card , значения card повторяется, мне нужно выбрать те token у которых card уникальный, не повторяется.* То есть из этих двух записей в итоговый набор не попадёт ни одна, верно?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:
select * from twocolumns t1 inner JOIN (select card from twocolumns group by card HAVING(count(card))=1) t2 on t1.card=t2.card